# Calcular diferença entre duas datas - não consigo converter a data do banco de dados para DateTime

Tags: php, laravel, data

Boa tarde!

Fiz uma função para calcular a diferença de dias entre duas datas, uma dessas datas é a atual (que crio usando o `new DateTime()`) e a outra pego no banco de dados e é salva como dateTime

```
foreach ($eventos as $e) {
    $qtdDias = $this->calculaDiferenca($e->dataEv);
    if ($qtdDias > 0 && $qtdDias <= 7) {
       array_push($evs,$e->id);
    }
}
function calculaDiferenca($DataEvento){
    $hoje = new DateTime();
    $diferenca = $hoje->diff($DataEvento);
    return $diferenca->d;
}
```

Como eu crio a coluna:

```
$table->datetime('dataEv')->nullable();
```

Quando executo da erro na linha em que eu calculo a diferença:

> DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string
>   given

Comment: O retorno de `dd($e->dataEv)`  tem o que como resultado? Veja a mensagem de erro, está retornando uma string, não um `DateTime`

Comment: Eu sei, esse é o problema. Eu preciso converter essa string em um DateTime

Comment: Qual é o formato/conteúdo dessa string retornada ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na variável $DataEvento. Ela é do tipo string e não DateTime. Você precisa transformá-la para o objeto DateTime

```
function calculaDiferenca($DataEvento){
    $hoje = new DateTime();
    $diferenca = $hoje->diff(new DateTime($DataEvento));
    return $diferenca->d;
}
```

Comment: Nossa, n acredito que era só isso! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que `$eventos` é um *array* com *models* do *Eloquent*, você pode converter automaticamente atributos usando um [*Date Mutator*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Eventos extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',  // Mantenha esses dois caso sua tabela tenha timestamps
        'updated_at',
        'dataEv'
    ];
}
```

Com isso `$e->dataEv` retornará uma instância de [`Carbon`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), que é um subtipo de `DateTime` e já funciona com seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma forma mais fácil...

```
$data_inicial = '2013-08-01';
$data_final = '2013-08-16';

$diferenca = strtotime($data_final) - strtotime($data_inicial);
//Calcula a diferença em dias
$dias = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));

echo "A diferença é de $dias entre as datas";
```

Qualquer duvida manda ai :)